# How to control the visibility of objectContribution in popupMenus?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

[image]

Hi guys,I had create a popupmenu with code above and this menu would be only showed if the folder's name matched "AAA".

Here is the problem:if there is a folder which is also named "AAA" after another folder,this menu would be showed,too.Actually we just wanna our popupmenu be showed in specific main folders,not their sub-folders.So how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an additional "visibility" tag for that contribution and then use a [PropertyTester](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions#Property_Testers) inside the visibility tag to check the name in more detail.